# Installing apps on separate hard drive

Tags: partitioning

I have a system with three storage drives:

```
SSD - boot              
HDD 1 - programs            
HDD 2 - storage
```

How do I get Ubuntu 13.10 to automatically install all apps to HDD 1 (software not packaged with the OS installation)? I know that apps are to be installed inside of `/`, but I want to install programs like the steam client, playonlinux installed programs, and software center managed programs on `HDD 1`.

How should I do this?

UPDATE:
How do I do this in terminal as well? I am using Zorin OS 7.1 variant of Ubuntu 13.10. Zorin OS does not have that UI based mount point editor only the run of the mill GParted

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd, http://askubuntu.com/questions/54770/how-can-i-install-applications-on-secondary-storage-hard-drive,

Answer (score 1):

As I know most of the Ubuntu applications are installed in  `/usr` . so while you creates the HDD 1 partition , set its mount point to `/usr` , so that all your applications will installed into HDD1 as you want.

I mean in this step( A sample image) , set mount point as /usr for HDD1

[image]

hope that helps.